# Export values from SQLite Database to CSV

Tags: c, csv, sqlite

I need to export values from an Sqlite table with 3 Columns to a CSV File.
Should write a loop and use the Select Query to Dump all Values or is there an inbuilt SQL Function to do this..

Im here

```
void writecsv()
{
   char c[1000];
   FILE *fptr;
   fptr=fopen("output.csv","w");

}
```

Comment: There isn't a built-in function to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `system` call to do it

```
system("sqlite3 -header -csv 'db2.db' 'select * from tdata;' > out.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not built into the SQLite lib, but you could use the `sqlite3` CLI with the commands `.mode csv` and `.output`. This is also scriptable by using an init file and reading the SQL commands from stdin/file.

Comment: Thanks.. i got it to work. plz see my answer...